# How to handle python objects built from a web API that have references to each other?

Tags: python, rest, design-patterns

I'm building a client library for a web API that exposes some objects like this:

```
# objs/foo/obj_id_1
{id: "foo_id_1"
 name: "your momma"
 bar: "bar_id_2"}

# objs/bar/obj_id_1
{id: "bar_id_2"
 name: "puh-lease"
 foo: "foo_id_1"}
```

So, objects of type `foo` have a reference to objects of type `bar` and vice versa.

In my python client library, I build python objects out of this API data.  A `Foo` instance will have a `bar` attribute containing a `Bar` instance instead of just the id of the `bar` and a `Bar` instance has a reference to a `Foo` instance in the `foo` attribute.

My python classes have `save` and `refresh` methods that POST or GET from the web API, and they do this for sub-objects.  For example, if I call `a_foo.refresh()`, this will also automatically call `a_foo.bar.refresh()`.

The above is a very simplified example, and there might be many different classes all referring to the same instance of `bar` or `foo` or any of the many other types of objects we get.

I think my question is actually two questions:

1. What is a good design or strategy to ensure that when I build an object from api data that all of its references to other objects point to the *same* object if I've already built that object from previous api requests?
2. When I call `save` or `refresh` what's a good design or strategy to prevent an infinite loop when two or more objects refer to each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty broad question.

1) One way would be to use the factory method pattern. Example:

```
def get_foo(_id):
    get_foo.foos = dict()
    def real_get_foo(_id):
        # get foo from the API
        get_foo.foos[_id] = foo
        return foo
    if _id in get_foo.foos:
        return get_foo.foos[_id]
    return real_get_foo(_id)
```

2) I don't think it's a good idea to make nested saves. If I write `foo.bar.x = 5` followed by `foo.save()` I wouldn't expect `bar` to get saved. Why? Because I called `save()` on `foo`, and I shouldn't have to worry about unwanted saves on related objects.

Answer (score 1):

For #1, you can use a 2-level dictionary holding the fetched objects

```
objectCache
    |- foo 
    |   |- foo_id_1 : <obj>
    |   |- foo_id_2 : <obj>
    |   |- ...
    |
    |- bar
    |   |- bar_id_1: <obj>
    |   |- bar_id_2: <obj>
    |   |- ...
    |   
    |- baz
    |   |- baz_id_1: <obj>
    |   |- baz_id_2: <obj>
    |   |- ...
    |
    |- ...
```

You'd use it like this:

```
def get_or_make_fetched_object(cls, id):
    return object_cache.setdefault(cls, {}).setdefault(id, cls())

my_foo = get_or_make_fetched_object(Foo, 'foo_id_1')
```

The trick part here is how to get rid of no longer referenced objects (for example if foo_id_1 switches from bar_id_1 to bar_id_35), in order to avoid memory leaks, as the `object_cache` dictionary will indefinitely keep a reference to the object, unless is removed from cache.

A possible approach to the memory usage problem would be a cleanup function that uses [gc.get_referrers()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html#gc.get_referrers) to obtain the `refcount` for each cached object. Basically objects in cache that have `refcount` equal to 2 can be removed from the cache (1 count comes from `gc`, the other one from the cache). This will not work for circular references though...

As for #2, you can timestamp an object with a save date, objects that match the current saving timestamp will be skipped in order to avoid infinite recursion. However it would make sense to save only subordinated objects.